# Edit text fields are overlapped(content before rotation covers the default content) when device is rotated and activity layout is in relative

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I am trying to make a note taking app.
I attach a fragment to the activity depending on a choice made by the user.

If my activity layout file root element is in linear layout, the attaching works fine even when device is rotated.
But when I put the activity in Relative layout, on rotating the device, the app displays double data fields : i.e data changed before rotating overlapped by the default.

**Fragment layout file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            tools:context="jsb.com.notetaker.NoteEditFragment">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/s"
    android:id="@+id/edit_note_item_icon"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/edit_note_item_icon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/edit_note_item_icon">

    <EditText
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edi_note_title_view"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edit_note_item_icon">

    <EditText
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_note_body_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</ScrollView>
```

**Activity Layout File (in Relative layout)**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="jsb.com.notetaker.NoteDetailActivity">
```

The data in the Edit Text fields overlaps whenever there is a rotation of device.

Does Relative view retain previous data because when i use linear layout for activity file, it works fine and no overlapping occurs

**This is how i fill data into the fragment fields when it is opened**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_edit,container,false);

    imageButton = (ImageButton) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_note_item_icon);
    editBody = (EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_note_body_view);
    editTitle = (EditText)fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_note_title_view);

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

    String title = intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_KEY);
    String body = intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_BODY_KEY);
    Note.Category category = (Note.Category) intent.getExtras().getSerializable(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_KEY);

    imageButton.setImageResource(Note.getCategoryImageFromCategory(category));
    editTitle.setText(title);
    editBody.setText(body);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_edit, container, false);
}
```